# XMLUnit comparing ignoring the order of elements

Tags: java, xsd, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I have 2 XML. I have been using XMLUnit for comparing the  2 xml strings. The problem is I am not able to ignore the order in which elements occur. I tried overriding ElementQualifier as well as DifferenceListener but that didn't help for this scenario.

**Control XML**

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:anotation>
        <xs:description>
            <Description>Country</Description>
        </xs:description>
    </xs:anotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**Test XML**

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:anotation>
        <xs:description>
            <Description>Country</Description>
        </xs:description>
    </xs:anotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Note that in Test XML another sequence is added and last element(country) of 1st sequence is removed.

XMLUnit complains about not having the element named `city` which is there in second sequence. Its taking the elements in Order. I tried Overriding **ELementNameAndAttributeQualifier** but didnt produced the desired result.Moreover, overriding **RecursiveElemenNameAndTextQualifier** didnt help either. The reason **RecursiveElemenNameAndTextQualifier** doesn't work because theres is no match for the 1st sequence. How would I approach and make sure

```
public boolean qualifyForComparison(Element element, Element element1) 
{
       // should return true only when **element 1** has all elements of  **element**
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really a bit more complex than "ignore element order", isn't it? :-)

`ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier` would be fine for the `xs:element` elements, but your real problem is making XMLUnit pick the correct `xs:sequence` elements. I really recommend you use XMLUnit 2.x as it's conditional element selector builder is something you'll need and replicating that in XMLUnit 1.x is a bit of a pain.

If your custom element selector did what your comments say, then you wouldn't select the `xs:sequence` elements you want to compare at all. The "test" sequence didn't contain the "street" `xs:element` and this the `ElementNameQualifier` would return `false`.

I'm not really sure what the exact logic you want would have to look like. What you describe in you comment would be something like (using XMLUnit 2.x, untested)

```
public boolean canBeCompared(Element e1, Element e2) {
    NodeList e1Children = e1.getChildNodes();
    NodeList e2Children = e2.getChildNodes();
    Iterable<Map.Entry<Node, Node>> matches =
        new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes)
        .match(new IterableNodeList(e1Children), new IterableNodeList(e2Children));
    for (Map.Entry<Node, Node> m : matches) {
        if (m.getKey() == null // test child with no matching control child
            || m.getValue() == null // control child with no matching test child
        ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There is no builtin way to do it, you really need to work against the DOM on your own.

Finally you'd use something like

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed(new QName("sequence", XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI))
    .thenUse(the element selector built above)
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes)
    .build();
```

when feeding the difference engine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to override **ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes** depending on our needs

Comment: sure, this is just what I guessed is what you need. You can provide any implementation of `ElementSelector`.